# replace '()' from a dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and it contains some values like

```
the change (♠)
and the new (⦻)
```

my desired output is

```
the change
and the new
```

I have tried to use

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(' ()')
df=df.replace('\()','',regex=False)
```

but nothing worked, can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Try `df = df.replace('\(\)','',regex=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dataframe:

```py
              col1           col2
0           value1  the change ()
1    the change ()         value3
2           value2         value4
3  () other change            NaN
```

You can replace the `()` in *whole* dataframe:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"\s*\(\)\s*", "", regex=True))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           col1        col2
0        value1  the change
1    the change      value3
2        value2      value4
3  other change         NaN
```

---

EDIT: If you have df:

```
              col1            col2
0           value1  the change (♠)
1   the change (⦻)          value3
2           value2          value4
3  () other change             NaN
```

Then:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"\s*\(.*?\)\s*", "", regex=True))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           col1        col2
0        value1  the change
1    the change      value3
2        value2      value4
3  other change         NaN
```

Comment: I have a little update in the question, can you again help? Thanks

Comment: then I am getting "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!" this error

Comment: @sdave You have probably some numeric columns. you can do `df['column name'] =  df['column name'].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"\s*\(.*?\)\s*", "", regex=True))`

Comment: I tried already with the way you suggested above comment.
```df = df.replace(r"\s*\(.*?\)\s*", '', regex = True, inplace = False)```
this way it worked, I am trying to double check if the results are fine as the table is huge and then will update.  But I am not sure how ```inplace = False``` worked

Comment: Hi again, so i used it and it worked but can you exaplain me what exactly is happening in this ```r"\s*\(\)\s*``` line?

Comment: @sdave `\s*\(\)\s*` is regular expression. It will find all `()` with any number of whitespaces (`\s*`) before and after.

Comment: and then when we add  ```.*?```  in ```r"\s*\(.*?\)\s* ``` how does it work?

Comment: @sdave This will match all text inside the `( )` - you can play with regular expression here for example: https://regex101.com/r/87WnG2/1

Answer (score 1):

You have almost done it. Just change `regex = True` in your code and modify the regex to remove the spaces as well.

Input dataset

```
         col1             col2
0   change ()             val1
1        val2  samplestring ()
2  change 2()          val 5()
```

```
df.replace(r'\s*\(\s*\)\s*', '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

Output dataset:

```
       col1          col2
0    change          val1
1      val2  samplestring
2  change 2         val 5
```

Comment: I have updated my question, can you have a look please

Comment: In this case, we get empty dataframe :(

Comment: Yes, because it was only looking for blank spaces between ().
You can try this:

`df.replace(r'\s*\(.*?\)\s*', '', regex = True,  inplace = True)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907458/remove-spaces-from-dataframe-pandas-python can you have a look at this please

Comment: df = df.replace(r"\s*\(.*?\)\s*", '', regex = True, inplace = False) this way it worked. But I am not sure how inplace = False worked ?

Comment: There is no need to write `inplace = False` if you are doing `df = df.replace(r"\s*(.*?)\s*", '', regex = True, inplace = False)`. Because here, you are explicitly assigning the dataframe returned from replace function back to `df` again.